# Check if files in cache are present for travis

Tags: travis-ci

Currently I have to build a dependency by source on every build and is often taking 5-6 minutes of a 10 minute build.
I found that you can cache files:
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/

But I only want to build it again if the cache is present (caches expire and get removed)

What is the best way to perform this check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in bash:

```
if [ ! -f "/etc/bebebe" ]; then echo "The file does not exist"; fi
```

Comment: do you know when the cache is loaded during the build process?
It is not described.

Comment: @dtracers you can see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/job-lifecycle/#the-job-lifecycle - cache is loaded after `apt` installs and before the `before_install` phase

Comment: I have looked forever for that exact list!
Thanks!